# Accessing controller's scope from Formly expressions

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

What is the correct way to access controller's scope (i.e. `$scope`) in [Formly's expressions](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v6.4.0/docs/formly-expressions)?

---

My use case:

I have a property, e.g. `$scope.showEmailField = false` and I want to have my Formly field to be hidden when this property is set to `false`. I've tried to use `hideExpression: 'showEmailField'`, but it looks like Formly creates it's own child scope. The only way I found is to use `$parent.showEmailField` expression, but it's not a good practice and expression is not tracked correctly that way. I have had to move `showEmailField` to the model object and use the following expression: `model.showEmailField`. That works OK, but it is somewhat ugly workaround.

---

I've re-read the documentation on expressions, field configurations and other things several times, but I couldn't grasp the concept of how all this context and scopes work with Formly. Maybe we need a good explanatory article on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best solution for your problem is using an anonymous function for hideExpression like this:

```
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl($scope) {
        var vm = this;          
        $scope.showEmailField = false;        
        vm.fields = [      
          {
            key: 'email',
            type: 'input',
            templateOptions: {
            type: 'email',
              label: 'email',
            },
            hideExpression: function(){         
              return $scope.showEmailField ;          
            }
          }
        ];
    });
```

for more detail you can read [this link](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v7.2.0/docs/field-configuration-object#hideexpression-string--function) in angular formly documents.most of formly field configurations accept a function argument to handle some miscellaneous expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
var fields = [{            
        key: 'email', 
        type: 'input',              
        templateOptions: {                
            label: 'Email',               
            required: true,              
            disabled: false,
            options:[1,2,3]             
        }, 
        expressionProperties: { 
            'templateOptions':function($viewValue,$modelValue,scope){               
             }
        }         
    }
]
```

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so.